# Getting all values from one column based on criteria in another column and auto-updating

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with data formatted like so:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| firstName | lastName  |
+-----------+-----------+
| jim       | jimson    |
| jan       | janson    |
| jim       | wazowski  |
| susie     | susieson  |
+-----------+-----------+
```

In another sheet, I want to be able to provide a firstName and get back all lastNames with that firstName, and I want this to update as I change the firstName.

For example, I should be able to put "jim" into the cell and my destination column will have

```
jimson
wazowski
```

then change the cell to "susie" and my destination column will have

```
susieson
```

This can be accomplished in Google Sheets with a simple filter of

```
=FILTER(lastName, firstName=A1)
```

Where A1 is the cell to input "jim" or "susie" but I can't seem to figure it out in Excel or find much documentation on this issue.

Comment: Appears this functionality is [limited to Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) with a simple built-in WS function.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's impossible. To perform this same functionality, you might have to do this in VBA using the `Worksheet_Change()` event that will update your sheet when a value is entered. With being VBA, this may be slightly slower. Or wait for someone like Scott Craner to show up with a miracle formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formula solution given you have a reasonable number of output possible:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$4,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$1:$A$4)*($A$1:$A$4=$E$1))/(1*($A$1:$A$4=$E$1)),ROW())),"")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is working pretty well! You said "given you have a reasonable number of output possible" but I'm not sure what you mean by that. Also, when I try this on a sheet of about 6,000 rows, it's only getting some of the results, not all. Is that what you meant by your comment and if so, why is that the case?

Comment: For the number of output I meant that you have to set your result range before hand, it is not dynamic in size. If you drop the formula in 20 rows, you'll get 20 results at max. If your expected number of results is within the output range size and you are still missing some of it, check that your result range starts in row 1 "F1" in my example, if not, you'll have to adapt the `ROW()` argument like `ROW()-1` if your first formula is in row 2.

Comment: Great thank you so much! Can you please give a reference to where I can read up on the usage of * and / as you did in the formula?

Comment: Not sure where you can read on this but `*` multiplies and also conveniently converts `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `1` and `0` and `/` divides. In short, this formula check if `jim=jim` if yes then 1 if not then 0 and then divided by itself gives 1 for 1 and `#DIV/0!` for 0. The `AGGREGATE()` function allows us to discard errors from an array leaving us only with the rows number where `jim=jim` that with use with the `INDEX()` formula to return the matching values. You can use `F9` to partially evaluate a formula in the formula bar, giving you visual help on whats going on or the `Evaluate Formula`